# Как подключить wikipedia api к вк боту на python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, вконтакте, mediawiki, mediawiki-api

Я пытался добавить в чат бота возможность пользователя запрашивать информацию которую бот ищет в wikipedia и выдает ответ, вот код:

```
import os
from random import randint
from requests import *
import vk
import wikipedia



# Указываем ключи доступа, id группы и версию API
VK_API_ACCESS_TOKEN = 'мой токен'
VK_API_VERSION = '5.103'
GROUP_ID = мой ид

wikipedia.set_lang("RU")


session = vk.Session(access_token = VK_API_ACCESS_TOKEN)
api = vk.API(session, v = VK_API_VERSION)

# Первый запрос к LongPoll: получаем server и key
longPoll = api.groups.getLongPollServer(group_id = GROUP_ID)
server, key, ts = longPoll['server'], longPoll['key'], longPoll['ts']

while True:
    # Последующие запросы: меняется только ts
    longPoll = post('%s'%server, data = {'act': 'a_check',
                                         'key': key,
                                         'ts': ts,
                                         'wait': 25}).json()


    if longPoll['updates'] and len(longPoll['updates']) != 0:
        for update in longPoll['updates']:
            if update['type'] == 'message_new':
                Object = update['object']#выуживаем из множества update множество object
                Message = Object['message']#выуживаем из множества bject множество message

                print(Message['peer_id'],'\n',Message['from_id'],'\n',Message['text'])
                print ('---------------------------------')
                # Отправляем сообщение
                if Message['text']== 'Команды':
                    api.messages.send(
                    peer_id = Message['peer_id'],
                    random_id = Message['random_id'],
                    message='1.Конь \n2.Пшел \n3.Подскажи'
                    )

                elif Message['text']== 'Конь':
                    api.messages.send(
                    peer_id = Message['peer_id'],
                    random_id = Message['random_id'],
                    message='Нет, Лось'
                    )
                elif Message['text']== 'Пшел':
                    api.messages.send(
                    peer_id = Message['peer_id'],
                    random_id = Message['random_id'],
                    message='Куда?'
                    )
                elif Message ['text'] == 'Подскажи':
                    api.messages.send(
                    peer_id = Message['peer_id'],
                    random_id = Message['random_id'],
                    message='Что?'
                    )
                    #for z in longPoll['updates']:
                    if update['type'] == 'message_new':
                        o = update['object']#выуживаем из множества update множество object
                        p = o['message']
                        #if p['text'] != 'Что?' and p['text'] != 'Подскажи':
                        api.messages.send(
                        peer_id = p['peer_id'],
                        random_id = p['random_id'],
                        message='Вот, держи! \n' +str(wikipedia.summary(p['text'])))

                        break
                continue  

    # Меняем ts для следующего запроса
    ts = longPoll['ts']
```

Но по итогу получаю ошибку после нескольких секунд подвисания в виде длинной портянки о том что > Сделана попытка выполнить операцию на сокете при отключенной сети.
Сама ошибка ниже:

```
*Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Елена\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 156, in _new_conn
    conn = connection.create_connection(
  File "C:\Users\Елена\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 84, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "C:\Users\Елена\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 74, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
OSError: [WinError 10051] Сделана попытка выполнить операцию на сокете при отключенной сети
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Елена\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 665, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "C:\Users\Елена\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 387, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "C:\Users\Елена\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\http\client.py", line 1230, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Users\Елена\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\http\client.py", line 1276, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Users\Елена\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\http\client.py", line 1225, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Users\Елена\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\http\client.py", line 1004, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "C:\Users\Елена\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\http\client.py", line 944, in send
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\Елена\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 184, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "C:\Users\Елена\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 168, in _new_conn
    raise NewConnectionError(
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x03C6FEB0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10051] Сделана попытка выполнить операцию на сокете при отключенной сети
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Елена\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 439, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "C:\Users\Елена\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 719, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "C:\Users\Елена\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 436, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='ru.wikipedia.org', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /w/api.php?list=search&srprop=&srlimit=1&limit=1&srsearch=%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B8&srinfo=suggestion&format=json&action=query (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x03C6FEB0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10051] Сделана попытка выполнить операцию на сокете при отключенной сети'))
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Елена\Desktop\test\рабочая версия.py", line 75, in <module>
    message='Вот, держи! \n' +str(wikipedia.page(p['text'])))
  File "C:\Users\Елена\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\wikipedia\wikipedia.py", line 270, in page
    results, suggestion = search(title, results=1, suggestion=True)
  File "C:\Users\Елена\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\wikipedia\util.py", line 28, in __call__
    ret = self._cache[key] = self.fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Елена\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\wikipedia\wikipedia.py", line 103, in search
    raw_results = _wiki_request(search_params)
  File "C:\Users\Елена\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\wikipedia\wikipedia.py", line 737, in _wiki_request
    r = requests.get(API_URL, params=params, headers=headers)
  File "C:\Users\Елена\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 75, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Елена\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 60, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Елена\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 533, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Елена\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 646, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Елена\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 516, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='ru.wikipedia.org', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /w/api.php?list=search&srprop=&srlimit=1&limit=1&srsearch=%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B8&srinfo=suggestion&format=json&action=query (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x03C6FEB0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10051] Сделана попытка выполнить операцию на сокете при отключенной сети'))*
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сайт Википедии переехал с `http` на `https`, а автор библиотеки этого, видимо, не учёл (или просто забил), поэтому для корректной работы библиотеки придётся изменить её исходники.

---

Для этого идём в папку с `Python3` (или виртуальным окружением, если Вы его используете) и меняем файл `%PYTHON_PATH%\Lib\site-packages\wikipedia\wikipedia.py`:

- Строку

```py
API_URL = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php'
```

заменяем на

```py
API_URL = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php'
```

- Внутри функции `set_lang` меняем строку

```py
API_URL = 'http://' + prefix.lower() + '.wikipedia.org/w/api.php'
```

на

```py
API_URL = 'https://' + prefix.lower() + '.wikipedia.org/w/api.php'
```